# Reload UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to reload my pickerView after loading data from a query. However the pickerView is not reloading. I want the subjectPickerView to reload after subjectPickOption is appended.

```
query = PFQuery(className:"Subject")
query.addAscendingOrder("subjectId")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(object.objectId!) {
(subject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil && subject != nil {

        self.subjectPickOption.append(subject!["subject"] as! String)
        self.subjectPickerTextField.userInteractionEnabled = true


    } else {
        print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
     }
}
```

Where should I place my self.SubjectPickerView.reloadAllComponents()?

Answer (score 0):

Under the line:

```
self.subjectPickerTextField.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

add your reloadAllComponents, but most importantly you need to run it on the main thread as your data call is on a background thread and when you change UI things it needs to be in the main thread:

```
...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
   self.SubjectPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
...
```